# Why $Sym^{n}(\mathbb{C})=\mathbb{C}^{n}$ or $Sym^{n}([0,1])=\Delta^{n}$ is a $n$-simplex?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Why $Sym^{n}(\mathbb{C})=\mathbb{C}^{n}$ or  $Sym^{n}([0,1])=\Delta^{n}$ is a $n$-simplex. Where I can find theory about symmetric products?.($Sym^n(X):=X^n/S_n$ where $S_n$ is the symmetric group in $n$ letters.)

Answer (score 3):

Let $X=[0,1]$. A point in $X^n$ is an ordered sequence of $n$ elements of $X$, and a point of $X^n/S_n$ is then an *unordered* sequence of $n$ points of $X$, which can be canonically ordered in increasing order. Therefore, points in $X^n/S_n$ can be identified with sequences $(t_1,t_2,\dots,t_n)$ with $0\leq t_1\leq t_2\leq \cdots\leq t_n\leq 1$.

Now given such a sequence, let $t_0=0$, $t_{n+1}=1$ for convenience, and define $s_i=t_i-t_{i-1}$ for $i\in\{1,\dots,n+1\}$. Clearly the $s_i$ are non-negative and $s_1+s_2+\cdots+s_{n+1}=1$, so $(s_1,\dots,s_{n+1})$ is an element of the standard $n$-simplex $\Delta^n\subseteq\mathbb R^{n+1}$. Of course, the mapping from the $t$'s to the $s$'s is bijective, and if you work a little bit you can show it is bicontinuous (you need to use the definition of the topology on $X^n/S_n$), so you have an homeomorphism.

Can you do the other?